# induction proof for kleene star

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction, formal-languages, regular-expressions

i am going through some past exam paper questions on regular languages for some revision, and i am having a bit of trouble with converting general ideas into formal mathematical proofs.

the question is: **given regular expression $S$, prove formally that $S^* = (S^*)^*$**

intuitively i can tell that because S* is an infinite set, then concatenating any number of elements from that infinite set, to that same infinite set, still yields an infinite set of the same size; ie. anything that is in $(S^*)^*)$ must also be in $S^*$.

my problem is expressing this in a formal proof. here is what i have worked through so far (it is a bit all over the place and just a collection of ways to express the problem mostly)

$S^* = (S^*)^*$

this implies:

$S^* \subseteq (S^*)^*$ **and** $S^* \supseteq (S^*)^*$

if we assume that there exists $w_k$ such that $w_k \in S^*$

then the base case for the proof is:

$k = 0$   $(w_k = \epsilon)$ (empty word, always in $S^*$ and $(S^*)^*$ by definition)

$k = 1$   $(w_k \in S^*)$

and that's kind of where my ability to reason ends.

i think the rest of it will be something like:

$w_{k+1} = w_kx$

ie. $w_k$ concatenated with $x$ where $x \in S^*$

but how can i show that $w_{k+1} \in (S^*)^*$

any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $w\in S^*$.  Since $(S^*)^*$ contains all concatenations of any finite number of words from $S^*$, it certainly contains $w$, which is a concatenation of just one word from $S^*$.  So $S^*\subseteq(S^*)^*$.

Conversely, let $w\in(S^*)^*$.  By definition we have
$$w=w_1w_2\cdots w_n$$
for some $n\ge0$, where each $w_j$ is in $S^*$.  By definition again, each $w_j$ can be written as
$$w_j=w_{j1}w_{j2}\cdots w_{jm_j}$$
for some $m_j\ge0$, where each $w_{jk}$ is in $S$.  So
$$w=w_{11}\cdots w_{1m_1}w_{21}\cdots w_{2m_2}\cdots w_{n1}\cdots w_{nm_n}\ .$$
This is a concatenation of finitely many words from $S$, so it is in $S^*$.  Therefore $(S^*)^*\subseteq S^*$, and this completes the proof.